Why can't I get error when I want to open my colab link?
I edited a file on Colab about a month ago and only saved the link for myself. Now, when I try to access it, I get this error:

 Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

this is my link
My date and time is correct. I just want to find a way that download my file no matter i can edit it in colab or somewhere else.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have a link for the code i made in google colab. Now when I want to open that code with the link i get this error message : There was an error loading this notebook. Ensure that the file is accessible and try again.
